# Proof of A $\cap$ $B^c$ = $\emptyset$ $\implies$ A $\subseteq$ B

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Is this reasoning correct?

I have to prove A $\cap$ $B^c$ = $\emptyset$ $\implies$ A $\subseteq$ B

By taking the contrapositive, we get

A $\not\subseteq$ B $\to$ A $\cap$ $B^c$ $\not=$ $\emptyset$ $\iff$
A $\not\subseteq$ B $\to$ (A $\cap$ $B^c$ $\not\subseteq$ $\emptyset$) $\lor$ ($\emptyset$ $\not\subseteq$ A $\cap$ $B^c$)

We can discard $\emptyset$ $\not\subseteq$ A $\cap$ $B^c$, since it's false by the property of $\emptyset$ that states it's contained in all sets.

Thus, we have now A $\not\subseteq$ B $\to$ (A $\cap$ $B^c$ $\not\subseteq$ $\emptyset$)

From the hypothesis, we work to get the conclusion in the following manner:

$ A \not\subseteq B$

$\iff \lnot(x \in A \to x \in B)$
[By definition of $\subseteq$]

$\iff x \in A \land x \not\in B$

$\iff x \in A \land x \in B^c$
[By definition of compliment]

$\iff x \in A \cap B^c$
[By definition of $\cap$]

$\iff x \in A \cap B^c \land x \not\in \emptyset$
[By definition of $\emptyset$ as a set with no elements]

$\iff \lnot(x \in A \cap B^c \to x \in \emptyset)$

$\iff \lnot(A \cap B^c \subseteq \emptyset)$
[By definition of $\subseteq$]

$\iff A \cap B^c \not\subseteq \emptyset$

Comment: [+1] Yes, seems correct to me.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But its too long. A short and simpler answer is provided by @Bram28 below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, but it can be done a lot simpler:

Suppose $x \in A$. Now suppose $x \not \in B$. Then $x \in B ^C$, and so $x \in A \cap B ^C$, which contradicts $A \cap B^C = \emptyset$. So, $x \in B$. So $A \subseteq B$

Answer (score 1):

I think you can prove by contradiction? Assume the contrary, $ \forall~ a \in A$, if $ a \notin B$ then we have $ a \in B^c $. Contradiction. (since $ a \in A \cap B^c \neq \varnothing$.)

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B^c=\phi\iff$ $\forall x\in A\;(x\not \in B^c)\iff$ $\forall x\in A\;(x\in (B^c)^c)\iff$ $\forall x\in A\;(x\in B)\iff$ $\iff A\subset B.$

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

Assume $A \neq \emptyset $, and  $ B \neq \emptyset$.

Let $x \in A. $

Since $A \cap B^c = \emptyset $, implies $ x \notin  B^c$.

Hence $ x\in B$, I.e.

$A \subseteq B$ , q.e.d.