# Proof of $A^c \cup B = U \implies A \subseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

How could I prove $A^c \cup B = U \implies A \subseteq B$ ?

Comment: Perhaps you could describe your thoughts on this problem.  Have you started it?  What assumptions do you have?  How do prove $A\subseteq B$ (what are the right assumptions/conclusions for this statement)?

Comment: Are you familiar with De Morgan's Law?

Comment: You got 4 answers already. What's the problem?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan Sorry!! Been very, very busy studying the last couple of days. We are having all the midterm exams here in Argentina.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption, $A^c\cup B=U$. Taking complement to both sides we get $(A^c\cup B)^c=U^c$. Using De Morgan's Law at the left-hand side and the fact that $U^c=\emptyset$, we get $$A\cap B^c=\emptyset.$$ Hence, $A\subset B$. The details is given in your previous post found [in here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2245915/proof-of-a-cap-bc-emptyset-implies-a-subseteq-b?rq=1).

Answer (score 0):

We can suppose $B\neq\emptyset$ because if $B=\emptyset\implies A^C=U\implies A=\emptyset=B\implies A\subseteq B$

If $A=\emptyset$ then $A\subseteq B$ trivially. Then we assume $A\neq\emptyset\neq B \implies A^C\subsetneq U$.

Now we know that $A^C\cup B=(A\cap B^C)^C$; from this, using the assumption $A^C\cup B=U$ we have $(A\cap B^C)^C=U\implies A\cap B^C=\emptyset$ thus $A\subseteq B$ because no element of $A$ is in $B^C$

Answer (score 0):

We know $A \cup A^c = A \cup U\backslash A = U$ and by assumption $B \cup U \backslash A = U$ Now by $A \subseteq U$ we have $A \subseteq B$ or $A \subseteq U \backslash A$ but by definition $A \not\subseteq U \backslash A$ thus $A \subseteq B$ .

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in A$ then $x\notin A^c $.  But $x\in A^c\cup B $.  So $x\in B $.